# Fancy box - how to show slideshow from a single thumbnail

Tags: jquery, fancybox

My thumbnails are paginated so that on any one page there are only 6 thumbs, and about 4 pages (for a total of 24 images in a category)

if I set it up on one of the pages it just shows the 6 related images on that page.

How can I use Fancybox to show a slideshow of all 24 images?

Many thanks in advance!

Richard

Comment: Maybe post up the code you have already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how i do it (but with multiple)

```
/*Fotos de la galeria*/
var galPhotos = [{
  href: '../img/galeria/fondo1.jpg',
  'nextEffect': 'fade',
  'prevEffect': 'fade'
}, {
  href: '../img/galeria/fondo2.jpg',
  'nextEffect': 'fade',
  'prevEffect': 'fade'
}, {
  href: '../img/galeria/fondo3.jpg',
  'nextEffect': 'fade',
  'prevEffect': 'fade'
}, {
  href: '../img/galeria/fondo4.jpg',
  'nextEffect': 'fade',
  'prevEffect': 'fade'
}, {
  href: '../img/galeria/fondo5.jpg',
  'nextEffect': 'fade',
  'prevEffect': 'fade'
}, {
  href: '../img/galeria/fondo6.jpg',
  'nextEffect': 'fade',
  'prevEffect': 'fade'
}];
$('a#gallery').live('click', function() {
  $.fancybox(galPhotos);
});
```

this would launch the fancybox with as many images as you put in the array

Comment: This looks great. I didnt realize that you could call fancybox with a list in that way. (my fault for not reading the docs well enough!)

Comment: Nice! you can mark it as answer to your question if you think it is!

Comment: OK, I'm new to this. How do I mark this as an answer (which it is!)

Comment: I am glad! right at the bottom of the rating count (and arrows wich you can also use if you want to rate the answer) there is an empty checkmark. if you click on it, it will get green and marked ;)

Comment: thanks for upvote but you still need to mark it as an answer ;)

Comment: finally found the check mark (I thought it was just some kind of decoration to the page!)

Comment: I have a minor follow on question ... when I show the gallery as a bove, is there a way to start at specific position in the galPhotos array (eg. if I wanted to start at position 3 say) ... i tried using 'jumpto' but that didn't work