# Thumbnail Disappears After Being Clicked On

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

Here's the location of my template site for now, which you can click on [here](http://abrielshipley.com/new).

Right now I have the first thumbnail programmed to go through a gallery of images after the thumbnail is initially clicked and it goes through FancyBox; just like a person asked previously on StackOverflow, which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800152/fancy-box-how-to-show-slideshow-from-a-single-thumbnail).

Or, part of the jQuery I have for the one thumbnail on my website is:

```
var galPhotos1 = [
            {href : 'images/portfolio/smilehealthy_werewolfmtd.jpg','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'}, 
            {href : 'images/portfolio/smilehealthy_applemtd.jpg','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'},
            {href : 'images/portfolio/smilehealthy_vampiremtd.jpg','nextEffect' : 'fade',   'prevEffect'    : 'fade'}, 
        ];

        $('a#gallery1').live('click',function(){
            $.fancybox(galPhotos1);
        });
```

I wanted to know if there were any suggestions for how to make it so when you close the FancyBox gallery, the thumbnail doesn't disappear?

Any help is very much appreciated! =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @jfk for helping me! =]

I actually tried removing the 'a' link element out of the function and make it look like the code below:

```
$('#gallery1').live('click',function(){
    $.fancybox(galPhotos1); // call fancybox on clicking the element with id "gallery1"
});
```

It seemed to work and no longer have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are applying two different fancybox calls to the same element. Your HTML is

```
<a id="gallery1" class="fancybox"> ...etc
```

your two scripts that call fancybox are

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox(); // call fancybox for elements with class "fancybox"
```

and

```
$('a#gallery1').live('click',function(){
 $.fancybox(galPhotos1); // call fancybox on clicking the element with id "gallery1"
});
```

In this case exist a conflict that might be creating that odd behavior. Just remove the `class="fancybox"` attribute from your anchor and your thumbnail won't be removed.

```
<a id="gallery1"> ...etc
```

Comment: Hello @jfk it doesn't seem to be working. All it does is sit there dormant. When I enter in the picture link, it doesn't correspond to the jQuery created fancybox class.

Comment: I visited your site again and still I can see that the element has still both, the `ID` and the `class` : `<a id="gallery1" class="fancybox">` ... both selectors are bound to fancybox through different scripts.

Comment: Hey thank you for catching that! =] I had forgotten to update the page right after I did that. Updated!